# How to prevent gnome-mplayer from asking to resume at the latest position

Tags: gnome, mplayer

gnome-mplayer asks whether to resume at the latest position if the playback has been canceled before the end of the video in a previous run of the program. How can I prevent this, i.e. start every video (in `gnome-mplayer`) from the beginning without being bothered? I checked the settings dialog and search for the question in popular search engines.

Comment: smplayer has a setting in "general" called "remember time position".

Comment: So you're suggesting to switch players, right? Because changing the option there has nothing to do with changing the option in gnome-mplayer.

Comment: smplayer is based of mplayer so it might have the same options in the same place ;)

Comment: No, they really do not (checked again)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a workaround. (I didn't search much about it.)

1. Install sqliteman:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sqliteman sqlite3
   ```
2. Open gnome-mplayer media datastore

   ```
   sqliteman ~/.config/gnome-mplayer/gnome-mplayer.db
   ```
3. Add a trigger to reset `resume` column to `0` with any data update

   - Schema tab → main → Tables → `media_entries` → Right click on Triggers → Create trigger
   - Fill up as:

     ```
     CREATE TRIGGER "no_resume"
        AFTER 
        UPDATE OF "resume"
        ON media_entries
        FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
         UPDATE media_entries SET resume = 0;
     END
     ```

     Meaning:

     1. Create a trigger with name "no_resume" which will be executed after any update of "resume" values in "media_entries" table.
     2. Command to be run: For each row in "media_entries" table set "resume" to "0".
   - Click Create

Close sqliteman and launch gnome-mplayer again. It works for me in (Ubuntu 14.04). If I check back database all `resume` column is `0`.

Comment: That is a really clever workaround that solves my problem. In order to speed up things for other missing this feature, I created https://code.google.com/p/gnome-mplayer/issues/detail?id=712.